# resque produces NoMethodError on server, works locally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, resque

This works perfectly locally. I've just deployed to a server and it's suddenly starting producing this problem.

These tasks are scheduled in resque-scheduler, but when I run / queue them, they fail with the message shown below. They work as intended locally.

**Error**

```
undefined method `get_unsent_data' for GetUpdates:Class
/var/www/theapp/app/workers/get_updates.rb:20:in `perform'
```

**application.rb snippet**

The helpers and workers directories are added to the load paths.

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/app/workers)
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/app/helpers)
```

**get_updates.rb**

```
require 'net/http'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'activerecord-import' 

class GetUpdates
    include SoapHelper 
    @@queue = :simple

    def self.perform

        beginning = Time.now
        puts "Running GetUpdates:Perform NOW"
        product_count = 0
        contloop = true
        while(contloop == true) do
            @xml = Nokogiri::XML(get_unsent_data())
        ..private logic..
        end
    end
 end
```

Comment: please follow ruby code style..thanks

Comment: `@xml = Nokogiri::XML(get_unsent_data())` where `get_unsent_data()` this method has been defined?

Comment: can you please put the `SoapHelper` code as well

Comment: Perhaps you have to extend the `SoapHelper` and not include like `extend SoapHelper`